# How can I log database errors at ERROR level when using Camel and MyBatis in my Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-camel, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have an app built on Java, Spring Boot, Apache Camel, MyBatis, Oracle. It used the Java DSL approach to configuration.

Many of the routes poll the database for data:

```
@Component
public class DataChangesRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("mybatis:selectDataChanges?statementType=SelectList&initialDelay=1300&delay=5000")
                .autoStartup("true")
                .routeId("dataChanges")
                .choice().when(body().isNotNull())
                .log("Consuming data change: ${body}")
                .to("direct:sendDataChangeMessage");

        ...
```

If a database error occurs during the polling, i.e. in the "from" clause, I would like to log these at ERROR level.

However it seems that the default is that they get logged at WARN level.

To re-create an error situation, I have revoked a grant on one of the tables involved in the database query. This results in the following being logged.

```
[2023-05-24T15:32:40.040Z] [org.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger] [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectDataChanges] [214] [WARN ] Consumer Consumer[mybatis://selectDataChanges?delay=5000&initialDelay=1300&statementType=SelectList] 
failed polling endpoint: mybatis://selectDataChanges?delay=5000&initialDelay=1300&statementType=SelectList. 
Will try again at next poll. 
Caused by: [org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException - 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Having read the docs, I have tried to adding an `errorHandler` to the Route. I have also tried adding an `onException(Exception.class)` handler to the route.

Neither make any difference. It is as though the Exception doesn't get passed to either of those.

The `try() ... catch()` approach doesn't seem appropriate as all the examples I have seen show that being used around the steps within the route, but not around the `from` step itself.

Any suggestions about how to catch these errors and log them at ERROR level would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question here:

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/mybatis-component.html

There is a component configuration option `bridgeErrorHandler` that:

> Allows for bridging the consumer to the Camel routing Error Handler,
> which mean any exceptions occurred while the consumer is trying to
> pickup incoming messages, or the likes, will now be processed as a
> message and handled by the routing Error Handler. By default the
> consumer will use the org.apache.camel.spi.ExceptionHandler to deal
> with exceptions, that will be logged at WARN or ERROR level and
> ignored.

By default, that is set to `false`, so to set the to `true` I had to add this line to my application.properties:

```
camel.component.mybatis.bridge-error-handler=true
```